# regex matching questions

Tags: regex, pcre

Sorry to ask this dumb questions, I've been trying for hours and still couldn't solve it, I have the following test text:

```
00:05:28,628 --> 00:05:33,866
It is quite simply the most sophisticated
robot on planet Earth.

[AUDIENCE LAUGHING]

AUDIENCE:
BUDIENCE 1:
CUDIENCE 10:
```

I used this regex `([A-Z]*&\s{0,2}&[0-9]{0,2}:)` to match these texts

```
AUDIENCE:
BUDIENCE 1:
CUDIENCE 10:
```

It did not work, it seems my regex requires one space and one number, but I've specified in {0,2} for zero or more, how can I solve this?
ps: AUDIENCE is just an example, it can be any text and anywhere in the setence, but all capital and followed by zero or more spaces, zero or more digits, then :

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: What is the purpose of the ampersand `&`? There is no ampersand in "AUDIENCE"

Comment: @user202729, I'm not using any programs, just trying to edit some text from a document. The editor uses PCRE.

Comment: If it's not programming-related it's not on-topic here. Unless you happens to use some IDE/"programmer's editors" and edit some programming-language source code...

Comment: [Although apparently something like Notepad++ counts as one.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311935/are-text-editor-regex-questions-off-topic)

Comment: @ MonkeyZeus, I thought & is AND in regex.

Comment: @Michael Nope! Check out regex101 and it will tell you the literal meaning of any syntax you put in. Regex is a pattern matcher, not a logic operator; albeit you can abuse it and treat it as one.

Comment: @user202729 Regex is a beast in it's own right and is adopted as a feature in countless programming languages. Using regex in any capacity is completely on-topic here even if the source string is not programming related. The only faux pas that OP made is not specifying which flavor of regex they are using.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus (go post an answer on that meta question. Don't ask me.)

Comment: @user202729 I wasn't asking, I was informing you.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestion and comments, it's clearer now, still a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

If you enable multiline `/m` modifier then this will work:

```perl
^[A-Z]+ *\d*:
```

https://regex101.com/r/PkeUg6/1

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but  AUDIENCE is just an example, normally the text is all capital, and followed by 0 or more spaces, o or more digits and :, in this case how should be the regex?

Comment: @Michael More or less the same, see the update.

Comment: thanks so much for your update, it's clearer now and much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

A working example in Python:

```
import re
s = "00:05:28,628 --> 00:05:33,866\nIt is quite simply the most sophisticated\nrobot on planet Earth.\n\n[AUDIENCE LAUGHING]\n\nAUDIENCE:\n\nAUDIENCE 1:\nAUDIENCE 10:\n"
matches = re.findall("[A-Z]+\W*?\d*?:", s)
```

gives

```
['AUDIENCE:', 'AUDIENCE 1:', 'AUDIENCE 10:']
```

Comment: [A-Z]+ would potentially match anything other than "AUDIENCE" as well right?

Comment: It would, however they haven’t  mentioned that they want to extract exactly AUDIENCE, I assumed the requirement is to extract capitalised words (from the regex they mentioned) followed by a space or not followed by `:`.